# How can I make set_error_handler() call a method on an object?

Tags: php

I think about using the `set_error_handler()` functionality in PHP to handle most of the PHP errors in one place (logging them to a file). From the documentation it looks like if I can pass a function name to `set_error_handler()`. Nice! But I have an `ErrorManager` object which has a nice logging method. I want to use that `ErrorManager` object and write an special error handler method for it, and have `set_error_handler` call that `ErrorManager`.

Could I just do something like?:

```
set_error_handler($this->customErrorHandler);
```

Or would that be invalid?

Comment: From the manual entry for set_error_handler() (http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php): "...an array containing an object reference and a method name can also be supplied as the error_handler ."

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Pass in an array of the object and the method name to be called:

```
set_error_handler(array($this, 'customErrorHandler'));
```

[`set_error_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) takes a [callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback):

> Some functions like call_user_func()
>   or usort() accept user-defined
>   callback functions as a parameter.
>   Callback functions can not only be
>   simple functions, but also object
>   methods, including static class
>   methods.
>
> A PHP function is passed by its name
>   as a string. Any built-in or
>   user-defined function can be used,
>   except language constructs such as:
>   array(), echo(), empty(), eval(),
>   exit(), isset(), list(), print() or
>   unset().
>
> **A method of an instantiated object is
>   passed as an array containing an
>   object at index 0 and the method name
>   at index 1.**
>
> Static class methods can also be
>   passed without instantiating an object
>   of that class by passing the class
>   name instead of an object at index 0.
>
> Apart from common user-defined
>   function, create_function() can also
>   be used to create an anonymous
>   callback function. As of PHP 5.3.0 it
>   is possible to also pass a closure to
>   a callback parameter.

(emphasis added)

Answer (score 9):

In PHP 5.3 you could do it in a closure:

```
$that = $this;
set_error_handler( function() use ($that) { $that->customErrorHandler(); } );
```

Comment: `$this` is unavailable within closures in 5.3, isn't it?

Comment: true, you'd have to create an extra variable for it. I updated the code accordingly …

Answer (score 4):

[`set_error_handler`](http://www.php.net/set_error_handler) accepts a [`callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback) as parameter.

Quoting that page :

> A method of an instantiated object is
>   passed as an array containing an
>   object at index 0 and the method name
>   at index 1.

In your case, you want a callback that corresponds to a method *(Called '`customErrorHandler`')* of an object *(here, `$this`)* ; the callback would then be :

```
array($this, 'customErrorHandler')
```

So, you'd use this portion of code :

```
set_error_handler(array($this, 'customErrorHandler'));
```