# Why is a variable used by reference to the set_error_handler function closure undefined?

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, closures, pass-by-reference

While reading through the Laravel Framework source code I stumbled upon this code

```php
set_error_handler(function ($type, $msg) use (&$error) {
    $error = $msg;
});
```

in the `move()` function of `UploadedFile` class of the `symfony/http-foundation` package that Laravel uses [Here](https://github.com/symfony/http-foundation/blob/master/File/UploadedFile.php#L180)

Intelephense extension on VSCode raises a warning

> Undefined variable '$error'

Deeply apologize for the screenshot of code (just in case this is a bug in the extension and you can't reproduce, please tell me) Sorry

[image]

While researching this, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1966833/5581565) that passes a closure use to `set_error_handler`

```php
$that = $this;
set_error_handler( function() use ($that) { $that->customErrorHandler(); } );
```

My understanding is that `customErrorHandler()` is a function in the same class or context and it has to be defined outside the call

Searching for similar example on the official docs yield same results, [see here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#123459)

But the `UploadedFile` class of Symfony only define a private property `$error` global to the class so shouldn't it be like this?

```php
$error = $this->error;
set_error_handler(function ($type, $msg) use (&$error) {
    $error = $msg;
});
```

How does this code know to get the `$error` variable from the property without defining it?*

*that's if it's getting it from there, otherwise...

How is `$error` passed here? is the `undefined` warning legit? given the code does actually work (just curious)

Comment: Your IDE could be the problem, don't you think?

Comment: Yes I thought so, but don't know how to test to tell for sure (Editor*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&$error` is making the code work. Basically, it's assigning the `$error` variable to null when you pass the callable, and then inside, it's setting it to the error message, and used afterwards.

```
set_error_handler(function ($type, $msg) use (&$error) { $error = $msg; });
$moved = move_uploaded_file($this->getPathname(), $target);
restore_error_handler();
```

Then it is using the `$error` variable if it failed to move:

```
if (!$moved) {
    throw new FileException(sprintf('Could not move the file "%s" to "%s" (%s)', $this->getPathname(), $target, strip_tags($error)));
}
```

It's the same as:

```
$error = null;
set_error_handler(function ($type, $msg) use (&$error) { $error = $msg; });
```

Without the `&`, it will throw an undefined variable notice.

And no the `$error` variable is not related to the `error` property.

You can take this code for example:

```
function executeCallback($callable) {
    $callable();   
}

executeCallback(function () use (&$error) {
    $error = 'This is the error message.';
});

echo $error;
```

The `$error` variable is defined in the `use (&$error)` and used afterward. And the output of the `echo` would be:

> This is the error message.

Comment: Makes sense! so a pass by reference to assign it a null, otherwise it does assign it to the defined variable? I mean is it possible to override `This is the error message.` here by defining it?

Comment: Never mind, it does! thanks for the explanation! I get it now